# Not able to see App Name in Android application

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, menu, android-actionbar

I am not getting my Application name on the action Bar.

So please help me to get the reason why it's hidden and how to solve that.

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            android:id="@+id/my_Toolbar"
            layout="@layout/my_toolbar"

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add in your manifest file a label at the corresponding activity, for example:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="app_name"
```

You can also set a title programmatically in your activity:

```
  getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My app name");
```

Answer (score 0):

for kotlin:
    supportActionBar?.title = "My app name"